# JQuery selector to exclude child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using this click method to reveal additional classes inside a `.tile`

```
var $tiles = $('.tile');

$tiles.on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this); 
    $this.toggleClass('large'); // change layout of tile
    $this.children('.details').toggle(); // display additional info
})
```

Since a `.tile` may contain links, I'd like to limit the click functionality. I don't want the function to trigger when a link inside `.tile` is clicked.

**Edit:** While @antyrant's answer is working for normal links, I noticed in my example the problem persists with on of the links that uses fancyBox.

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="tile">
    <ul class="details">
        <li><a class="download"> href="#">Download</a></li>
        <li><a class="fancybox-media" href="#">Video</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Clicking the download link works fine, but the fancyBox will not work!

**Edit 2:** See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/idleberg/4wjKH/) for a working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [stop events propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) on child elements, for example:

```
$tiles.find( 'a' ).click( function( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**UPDATE:**
If this can be done as you use some plugins for example you can check if `event` `target` has your base class: for example:

```
$('.tile').on('click', function ( e ) {
    if( !$( e.target ).hasClass( 'tile' ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    //...
```

see [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4wjKH/14/).

Comment: or `.stopImmediatePropogation` when using delegation

Comment: This is a solution for normal links, but unfortunately this will prevent fancyBox from triggering as well. I've edited my question to include my HTML, maybe you can have another look.

Comment: @idleberg Look into @Waxen answer, you can check by className instead: `if( !$( e.target ).hasClass( 'fancybox-media' ) ) {`

Comment: @idleberg Maybe if you will have some demo link or jsFiddle will help more.

Comment: @antyrat Here's my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/idleberg/4wjKH/). You will notice, that clicking the the "Download" works as desired, while clicking the video link will shrink the box.

Comment: @idleberg ok, I've updated my answer for you, but as I was said in prev comments this is very similar to @Waxen answer, just in my case it will filter ALL childs, not only `a` elements

Comment: had some troubles with @Waxen's solution before, but your modified version is working perfectly. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

@antyrat is correct, stopping propagation on the anchors will achieve your goal, but that requires binding another event that isn't really necessary.  Another option would be to look at the target on the event passed in to your handler.

```
$tiles.on( 'click', function( e ) {
    if( !$( e.target ).is( 'a' ) ) { // if the element clicked is not an anchor.
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

EDIT: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Waxen/WbS2n/) demonstrating this working using the updated html provided above.

Answer (score 0):

stopPropagation() will stop your child event from bubbling up, and being caught by the listener on the parent element.

```
var $tiles = $('.tile');

$tiles.on('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked');
})

$('a', $tiles).on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); //Prevents event from bubbling up
})
```